# how to send message to azure event hub with partition key in python

Tags: python

newbie in python here. I am trying to send message with partition key to different event hub sink.

here's what I tried:

```
def ehubWriter(df:SparkDataFrame,
              conf:object = None,
              getpartitionKey: bool = False
             ):
      (
        df.select(f.to_json(f.struct("*")).alias("body"), (f.concat(f.col("userId"), f.lit("_"), f.col("companyId"))).alias("partitionKey"))
        .write.format("eventhubs").options(**conf).save()
      )
```

What I need to do here is to use the getpartitionKey and turn it into conditional so other eventhub sink can receive the partition Key.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the partition_key attribute available in either [EventData Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-eventhub/azure.eventhub.eventdata?view=azure-python#azure-eventhub-eventdata-partition-key) or [EventDataBatch Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-eventhub/azure.eventhub.eventdatabatch?view=azure-python) to specify the partition to send the event to. Could you please check if the below sample code snippet helps ?

```
from azure.eventhub import EventHubProducerClient, EventDataBatch

def ehubWriter(df:SparkDataFrame,
              conf:object = None,
              getpartitionKey: bool = False
             ):
    # Create an Event Hub producer client
    producer = EventHubProducerClient.from_connection_string(conf["eventhubs.connectionString"], eventhub_name=conf["eventhubs.name"])

    # Create an EventDataBatch object
    batch = producer.create_batch()

    # Iterate over the rows of the Spark DataFrame and add each row as an event to the batch
    for row in df.collect():
        # Create an EventData object with the row data
        event_data = EventData(row.asDict())

        # If getpartitionKey is True, set the partition key for the event
        if getpartitionKey:
            event_data.partition_key = row["partitionKey"]

        # Add the event to the batch
        batch.add(event_data)

    # Send the batch to the Event Hub
    producer.send_batch(batch)

    # Close the Event Hub producer client
    producer.close()
```

You can call the above function like below:

```
ehubWriter(df, conf, getpartitionKey=True) # sends messages to event hub with partition key
ehubWriter(df, conf, getpartitionKey=False) # sends messages to event hub without partition key
```